# windows store apps: implement advanced search

Tags: search, windows-8

what is the best way to implement advanced search in windows store apps? where user can provide certain search criteria and then click the search. can we use the search contract and still achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by _advanced search_, be specific.

Comment: I want to be able to add search criteria that the user can choose. like for example Search for houses of particular criteria. user should be able to choose price range, etc before searching. Can we add this in the search flyout? or do we need to implement it within the app and not use search contract for this?

Comment: Search charm bascially gets a keyword and based on keyword you can show the result. But if you want some advanced search then you have implement your own.